# Dual-Link DVI ExpressCard

Tags: laptop, resolution, hdmi, dvi

I'm looking for a way to connect a monitor with resolution 2560x1600 to my laptop, which only outputs single-link HDMI (max 2048 x 1536). The laptop has an ExpressCard slot, and I have noticed availability of a DVI adapter, but it is only single-link:

> http://www.amazon.co.uk/Startech-ExpressCard-Connection-Cable-PEX2PCI4/dp/B001CHCFDU/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1308922418&sr=1-1

Does anyone know of a dual-link equivalent?

Comment: It's very difficult that you will find one. ExpressCard has a USB 2.0 port and a 1x PCI-E port. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that 1x PCI-E isn't fast enough to drive dual link DVI.

Comment: eh, it looks like its using a DVI connector to connect to a 4 port PCI bay. its not a 'video card'.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - 1x PCIe will drive 2560x1600 just fine.  I've had FOUR running off a single ViDock 3.  (You do start to see a bit of latency, and don't even think about trying to play video, but four works!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Journeyman Geek said, it isn't a video card. It sounds like what you are looking for is an external graphics card, or an internal card in an external enclosure like [this one](http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock). I find it unlikely that an expresscard itself is going to be able to do the heavy lifting of powering a 2560x1600 display without the help of an external card, especially because of all the heat this will produce.

Comment: The linked ViDock 4 (the 3 was just discontinued, sadly) is the correct way to do this.  Be aware that certain laptop ExpressCard controllers just can't handle it, certain laptop BIOSes won't map the memory for the external card properly if there is too much RAM in the machine, and certain mobile graphics chipsets won't play nice with certain desktop chipsets.  But it can be made to work...and in fact if you can provide specifics I can probably tell you what'll happen, I have a LOT of experience with this particular configuration.

Comment: That's a wonderful piece of kit - far above my price range however.